# Use of loose and lose

Tags: confusable

Do we use loose or lose when a team has been defeated?

> For us to win the league,we must not loose/lose again.

I've always used lose.But,so often I see alot of people using loose,am I the one who is wrong?

Comment: Any dictionary should tell you that the correct answer is "[lose](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lose)".  It is easy to mistakenly type "[loose](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/loose)" instead of "lose".  Also, some people ([stereotypically in Chicago](https://infogalactic.com/info/Bill_Swerski%27s_Superfans)) pronounce both words the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could I loose my money?" What does this mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64215/could-i-loose-my-money-what-does-this-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Lose**
   It is a verb with the forms: lose, losing, lost
   The meaning of lose is:

   - fail to maintain, to be unable to find or keep something
     I will lose weight
     I lost my keys
   - Cease to have either physically or in an abstract sense.
     She lost her purse
     I lost my friend in the crowd
     Do not lose this opportunity
   - to fail to win
     We lost the match
     Lose a game
     Our team lost the game tonight
   - to fail to make money
     I will lose a fortune
2. **Loose**
   It is usually an adjective and sometimes a verb
   It means:

   - not firmly or tightly held in place, not tight
     I have a loose tooth
     My shoes are loose
     These trousers are loose
   - free from restraint, constraint or confinement
     There is a dog running loose in the street
   - to set free, release from fastenings, to undo (as verb)
     The animals have been loosed (as verb)
     The sails were loosed and we set off (as verb)
3. The best way to remember the difference between these words is to remember the following sentence:
   A goose is on the loose.
   This means that a goose has been unleashed and is free from confinement. If you can remember this sentence and say the words aloud while you are writing, you will be able to keep them straight.
4. Do we use loose or lose when a team has been defeated?
   We lose when a team has been defeated

[Writing Explained](http://writingexplained.org/lose-versus-loose-difference)
[e Learn English Language](http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/english-mistakes/loose-vs-lose/)
[Grammar monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/loose_lose.htm)